# Refreshing Activity When Dialog Dismisses

Tags: android, database, listview, dialog

Actually in my list activity,when user taps on any item ,a dialog box is opened with two options of delete and cancel.When user select delete button the dialog dismisses with deleting value in database.And the old list activity comes in foreground with old values.Though it is deleted it is showing in listview.Is there a way to show the refreshed list.If yes,then How?

Comment: paste your code. it may be helpful to give exact answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using array list then you must definitely know the item position and using that position you can remove item from your list .Then call the

```
     yourlist.remove(position);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

run your program to watch the magic.

Comment: Actually waqas has told it but i was not getting how to proceed.Thanx

Comment: @Akki-Delete is ok,if i am putting editing in dialog and save button is pressed,then what should i do o as it does not update list

Comment: Rather than doing `yourlist.remove(position);` I think it's a bit tidier just to clear the list and repopulate it, before calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Just my personal preference...

Comment: we have to run a query for whole bunch of data.so its better to remove just one data from it.

Answer (score 2):

you need to remove the deleted item from adapter too before calling adapter's notifyDataSetChanged() in order to refresh your list

Comment: @Waqas-Delete is ok,if i am putting editing in dialog and save button is pressed,then what should i do as it does not update list

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code,

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

make a function called: doTheAutoRefresh() that does:

```
private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             doRefreshingStuff(); // this is where you put your refresh code
             doTheAutoRefresh();
         }, 1000);
}
```

Call this function in your onCreate.

NOTE: this is the basic approach. consider stopping this after onPause has been called and to resume it after onResume. Look at the handler class to see how to remove.

Answer (score 1):

When closing the Dialog call

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

on your list adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
implement the dialog dismiss listener and check if the user has clicked on your "delete" button, if yes then perform your refresh

```
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

            }
        })
```

Refresh the listview by setting the apdater again....

Answer (score 0):

clear the list using list.clear();
and set the adapter like this
adapter = new Adapter(this);
`enter code here`listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: get the data from the database and once again add to list

Answer (score 0):

You can override activity method `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` and track the state of your activity.

Normally, if some alert dialog is shown above your activity, the activity does not get `onPause()` and `onResume()` events. But it loses focus on alert dialog shown and gains it when it dismisses.

In your case you can refresh your data in `onWindowFocusChanged()` if `hasFocus` is `true`.