# Refreshing activity / "performing stop of activity that is not resumed" error

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to refresh my activity once the GPS is enabled via an alertdialog that opens the GPS settings.
I implemented the onResume function but in result I get this on my logcat :

```
performing stop of activity that is not resumed(...)
```

I have looked on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289114/refreshing-activity-when-dialog-dismisses) but I can't figure out what is wrong with my code (or my onResume function) and how to refresh my activity after coming back from GPS settings.

can you help me please ?
here is my [MainActivity.java](https://gist.github.com/RidouaneHicham/24667b270ca5d4decae2)

Comment: why are you calling your activity again..that's obvious onResume() is called twice once when you start i.e. after onCreate() and other when you come back.

Comment: @MOSO I updated the onResume function with this line : this.onCreate(null); whice reloads the activity, but apparently it's not recommended to do it so...

Comment: it is not recommended for sure n not a right way to peogram as well. Have you got your problem fixed? you need to post your full code including your showsettingsalert() method then I can suggest something further if not yet solved.

Comment: @MOSO okay, here is my GpsTracker.java class that contains the showsettingsalert() function : https://gist.github.com/RidouaneHicham/680c88bc8e9b5cb7ceb6

Comment: you have defined the showsettingsalert() in service class. Why are you doing this when knowing that it doesn't have any UI so where will you recieve the result until you cast your context to the receiving MainActivity. Solution is to move your method to MainActivity class and do further stuff. I'm editing my answer below.

Comment: @MOSO thanks man, I will update my code this weekend and see what happends (have to do some reading about this StartActivityForResult and onActivityResult)..

Comment: upvote can be a better form of thanks so that others may find useful too. :p :D

Comment: @MOSO for now I'll stick with an easier solution (have no time to move functions and stuff for now, but I'm certainly doing it later!) the solution is to move all the stuff that I want to reload to the onResume function, this way I have my problem fixed withoud messing with the activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling your

```
gps.showSettingsAlert();//inside this use startActivityForResult(new Intent().setClass(this, MainActivity.class), result_code);
```

**Edit: your method should be in MainActivity.class not in Service as service don't have ui so no point of getting the result there.**

```
  public void showSettingsAlert(Context context){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertdialog.setTitle("Oups ! pas de données GPS");
            alertdialog.setMessage("GPS n'est pas activé sur votre appareil, voulez vous l'activer ?");

            /*
            handling the buttons :
             */
            alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CODE_GPS);


                }
            });

            // on pressing cancel button
            alertdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            alertdialog.show();

        }
```

---

Here is your Activity result method which will be called after user presses back from Settings page.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            if(requestCode == RESULT_CODE_GPS && resultCode == 0){
              //  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
                if(provider != null && !provider.isEmpty()){
                    Log.v("mAINaBBB", " Location providers: "+provider);
                    //Start searching for location and update the location text when update available. 
    // Do whatever you want

                }else{
                      Log.v(, "Nothing put on");
                    //Users did not switch on the GPS
                }
            }
        }
```

---

Now in the MainAcitivity itself call the method where you called before

```
if(gps.canGetlocation() ){

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            device_location = new ParseGeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings

            showSettingsAlert(MainActivity.this); //**This line should be changed then**
        }
```

Comment: I did as you said (used the startactivityforresult inside the showsettingsalert() function, but I get this error : Cannot resolve method 'satrtactivityforresult(android.content.intent,int)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error - and I found it was due to my code mistake -
I was reloading the self activity again - which was sort of creating an infinite loop.

I got rid of it by taking it out of infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity.onResume() you attempt to start a new MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent refresh =new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
}
```

This is just a *bad idea* and will give an infinite loop, where a MainActivity is constantly starting a new MainActivity.

Just delete your onResume() and refresh the views of the current activity, instead of creating new ones.